# PHP - Searching for a variable match within another variable

Tags: php, regex

I'm stuck with this problem which seems relatively simple.  I have a table full of product id numbers stored as variable $partnumber.  When processing changes in inventory I need to know if an entire $partnumber string is within another $partnumber string.
For example, I need to know if PRA-LGL70-B2-BKWH-EC-L69A7330 exists within other variable strings such as the ones below.

PRA-LGL70-B2-BKWH-EC-L69A7330

PRA-LGL70-B2-BKWH-EC-L69A7330-L6901

PRA-LGL70-B2-BKWH-EC-L69A7330-L6901-L5156

There are tens of thousands of these partnumbers in a table and I've been told that preg_match might be too slow.  Unfortunately, I cannot change the actual data so the only potential delimiter is "-".  I'm sorry that I don't have any source code because I just started on this problem.  Can anyone point me in right direction?

Comment: I don't understand your "thinking". `I just started on this problem` and you directly ask on SO? Try something! You tag this as `regex` but you say that `preg_match()` is slow. So what do you expect? Anyways, if you only need to know if it "exists", take a look at `strpos()` or `stripos()`. On that note you have a **-1** from me

Comment: You should do this directly in the database, not in php.

Answer (score 2):

Without more details it is hard to know the requirements of your problem.  As mentioned in the comments, it is probably better to do this in the database. But to directly answer your question - `PHP - Searching for a variable match within another variable` use `strpos()`:

```
$partnumber = 'PRA-LGL70-B2-BKWH-EC-L69A7330-L6901';

$search_for = 'PRA-LGL70-B2-BKWH-EC-L69A7330';

if (strpos($partnumber, $search_for)!==false)
    echo "Match found";
```

Note: `stripos()` will do the same thing, but will not consider case.

Comment: +1 to strpos, strstr, mb versions etc.